# sharp smart tv will not show my app on google play store

Tags: android, smart-tv

I have published an Android TV app to the google play store. The two Sharp smart tv's we purchased to run this app, will only let us see certain apps when searching the google play store. Ours does not show up.

I have gone through all setting that would block app installation for any reason. I have been able to find and install this app on a LG smart tv running the same Android system 8.

I was expecting to install these apps to run our digital menu boards for our tap room...and now somehow Sharp is blocking me from doing so. Their technical support says it’s a google issue which is obviously not the problem since we have been able to find and install the app on 4 other tv brands.

Is there any way to install the apk file on the tv using USB or anything?

Comment: Unclear which specific model of Sharp Android TV you are testing on.

Comment: 75”AQUOS running Android 8. model:LC-75Q7570U